# Quicksort: Choosing the pivot

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode, quicksort

When implementing Quicksort, one of the things you have to do is to choose a pivot. But when I look at pseudocode like the one below, it is not clear how I should choose the pivot. First element of list? Something else?

```
 function quicksort(array)
     var list less, greater
     if length(array) ≤ 1  
         return array  
     select and remove a pivot value pivot from array
     for each x in array
         if x ≤ pivot then append x to less
         else append x to greater
     return concatenate(quicksort(less), pivot, quicksort(greater))
```

Can someone help me grasp the concept of choosing a pivot and whether or not different scenarios call for different strategies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688264/improving-the-quick-sort

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Choosing a random pivot minimizes the chance that you will encounter worst-case O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance (always choosing first or last would cause worst-case performance for nearly-sorted or nearly-reverse-sorted data).  Choosing the middle element would also be acceptable in the majority of cases.

Also, if you are implementing this yourself, there are versions of the algorithm that work in-place (i.e. without creating two new lists and then concatenating them).

Comment: I would second the notion that implementing a search yourself might not be worth the effort. Also, be careful how you're picking random numbers, since random number generators are kinda slow sometimes.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler's answer is better

Answer (score 76):

It depends on your requirements.  Choosing a pivot at random makes it harder to create a data set that generates O(N^2) performance.  'Median-of-three' (first, last, middle) is also a way of avoiding problems.  Beware of relative performance of comparisons, though; if your comparisons are costly, then Mo3 does more comparisons than choosing (a single pivot value) at random.  Database records can be costly to compare.

---

Update: Pulling comments into answer.

[mdkess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31455/mdkess) asserted:

> 'Median of 3' is NOT first last middle. Choose three random indexes, and take the middle value of this. The whole point is to make sure that your choice of pivots is not deterministic - if it is, worst case data can be quite easily generated.

To which I responded:

- [Analysis Of Hoare's Find Algorithm With Median-Of-Three Partition](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.39.1103) (1997)
  by P Kirschenhofer, H Prodinger, C Martínez supports your contention (that 'median-of-three' is three random items).
- There's an article described at [portal.acm.org](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1176.1243&coll=GUIDE&dl=GUIDE&CFID=20869026&CFTOKEN=55062919) that is about 'The Worst Case Permutation for Median-of-Three Quicksort' by Hannu Erkiö, published in The Computer Journal, Vol 27, No 3, 1984. [Update 2012-02-26: Got the text for the [article](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/3/276).  Section 2 'The Algorithm' begins: '*By using the median of the first, middle and last elements of A[L:R], efficient partitions into parts of fairly equal sizes can be achieved in most practical situations.*'  Thus, it is discussing the first-middle-last Mo3 approach.]
- Another short article that is interesting is by M. D. McIlroy, ["A Killer Adversary for Quicksort"](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~doug/mdmspe.pdf), published in Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 29(0), 1–4 (0 1999).  It explains how to make almost any Quicksort behave quadratically.
- AT&T Bell Labs Tech Journal, Oct 1984 "Theory and Practice in the Construction of a Working Sort Routine" states "Hoare suggested partitioning around the median of several randomly selected lines. Sedgewick [...] recommended choosing the median of the first [...] last [...] and middle".  This indicates that both techniques for 'median-of-three' are known in the literature. (Update 2014-11-23: The article appears to be available at [IEEE Xplore](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel7/6731004/6771897/06771921.pdf?arnumber=6771921) or from [Wiley](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/j.1538-7305.1984.tb00067.x/abstract) — if you have membership or are prepared to pay a fee.)
- ['Engineering a Sort Function'](http://www.cs.fit.edu/~pkc/classes/writing/samples/bentley93engineering.pdf) by J L Bentley and M D McIlroy, published in Software Practice and Experience, Vol 23(11), November 1993, goes into an extensive discussion of the issues, and they chose an adaptive partitioning algorithm based in part on the size of the data set.  There is a lot of discussion of trade-offs for various approaches.
- A Google search for 'median-of-three' works pretty well for further tracking.

Thanks for the information; I had only encountered the deterministic 'median-of-three' before.

Comment: Median of 3 is NOT first last middle. Choose three random indexes, and take the middle value of this. The whole point is to make sure that your choice of pivots is not deterministic - if it is, worst case data can be quite easily generated.

Comment: I was reading abt introsort which combines good features of both quicksort and heapsort. The approach to select pivot using median of three might not always be favourable.

Comment: The problem with choosing random indices is that random number generators are pretty expensive. While it does not increase the big-O cost of sorting, it will probably make things slower than if you had just picked the first, last, and middle elements. (In the real world, I bet nobody is making contrived situations to slow down your quick sort.)

Answer (score 28):

Heh, I just taught this class.

There are several options.
Simple: Pick the first or last element of the range. (bad on partially sorted input)
Better: Pick the item in the middle of the range. (better on partially sorted input)

However, picking any arbitrary element runs the risk of poorly partitioning the array of size n into two arrays of size 1 and n-1.  If you do that often enough, your quicksort runs the risk of becoming O(n^2).

One improvement I've seen is pick median(first, last, mid); 
In the worst case, it can still go to O(n^2), but probabilistically, this is a rare case.

For most data, picking the first or last is sufficient.  But, if you find that you're running into worst case scenarios often (partially sorted input), the first option would be to pick the central value( Which is a statistically good pivot for partially sorted data).

If you're still running into problems, then go the median route.

Comment: We did an experiment in our class, getting the k smallest elements from an array in sorted order.  We generated random arrays then used either a min-heap, or randomized select and fixed pivot quicksort and counted the number of comparisons.  On this "random" data, the second solution performed worse on average than the first.  Switching to a randomized pivot solve the performance problem.  So even for supposedly random data, fixed pivot performs significantly worse than randomized pivot.

Comment: Why would partitioning the array of size n into two arrays of size 1 and n-1 run the risk of becoming O(n^2)?

Comment: Assume an Array of size N.  Partition into sizes [1,N-1].  The next step is partitioning the right half into [1, N-2]. and so on, until we have N partitions of size 1.  But, if we were to partition in half, we'd be doing 2 partitions of N/2 each step, leading to the Log(n) term of the complexity;

Answer (score 21):

Never ever choose a fixed pivot - this can be attacked to exploit your algorithm's worst case O(n<sup>2</sup>) runtime, which is just asking for trouble. Quicksort's worst case runtime occurs when partitioning results in one array of 1 element, and one array of n-1 elements. Suppose you choose the first element as your partition. If someone feeds an array to your algorithm that is in decreasing order, your first pivot will be the biggest, so everything else in the array will move to the left of it. Then when you recurse, the first element will be the biggest again, so once more you put everything to the left of it, and so on.

A better technique is the **median-of-3 method**, where you pick three elements at random, and choose the middle. You know that the element that you choose won't be the the first or the last, but also, by the central limit theorem, the distribution of the middle element will be normal, which means that you will tend towards the middle (and hence, nlog(n) time).

If you absolutely want to guarantee O(nlog(n)) runtime for the algorithm, the **columns-of-5 method** for finding the median of an array runs in O(n) time, which means that the recurrence equation for quicksort in the worst case will be:

```
T(n) = O(n) (find the median) + O(n) (partition) + 2T(n/2) (recurse left and right)
```

By the Master Theorem, this is O(nlog(n)). However, the constant factor will be huge, and if worst case performance is your primary concern, use a merge sort instead, which is only a little bit slower than quicksort on average, and guarantees O(nlog(n)) time (and will be much faster than this lame median quicksort).

[Explanation of the Median of Medians Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545795/explanation-of-the-median-of-medians-algorithm)

Answer (score 7):

Don't try and get too clever and combine pivoting strategies. If you combined median of 3 with random pivot by picking the median of the first, last and a random index in the middle, then you'll still be vulnerable to many of the distributions which send median of 3 quadratic (so its actually worse than plain random pivot)

E.g a pipe organ distribution (1,2,3...N/2..3,2,1) first and last will both be 1 and the random index will be some number greater than 1, taking the median gives 1 (either first or last) and you get an extermely unbalanced partitioning.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to break the quicksort into three sections doing this

1. Exchange or swap data element function
2. The partition function
3. Processing the partitions

It is only slightly more inefficent than one long function but is alot easier to understand.

Code follows:

```
/* This selects what the data type in the array to be sorted is */

#define DATATYPE long

/* This is the swap function .. your job is to swap data in x & y .. how depends on
data type .. the example works for normal numerical data types .. like long I chose
above */

void swap (DATATYPE *x, DATATYPE *y){  
  DATATYPE Temp;

  Temp = *x;        // Hold current x value
  *x = *y;          // Transfer y to x
  *y = Temp;        // Set y to the held old x value
};


/* This is the partition code */

int partition (DATATYPE list[], int l, int h){

  int i;
  int p;          // pivot element index
  int firsthigh;  // divider position for pivot element

  // Random pivot example shown for median   p = (l+h)/2 would be used
  p = l + (short)(rand() % (int)(h - l + 1)); // Random partition point

  swap(&list[p], &list[h]);                   // Swap the values
  firsthigh = l;                                  // Hold first high value
  for (i = l; i < h; i++)
    if(list[i] < list[h]) {                 // Value at i is less than h
      swap(&list[i], &list[firsthigh]);   // So swap the value
      firsthigh++;                        // Incement first high
    }
  swap(&list[h], &list[firsthigh]);           // Swap h and first high values
  return(firsthigh);                          // Return first high
};



/* Finally the body sort */

void quicksort(DATATYPE list[], int l, int h){

  int p;                                      // index of partition 
  if ((h - l) > 0) {
    p = partition(list, l, h);              // Partition list 
    quicksort(list, l, p - 1);        // Sort lower partion
    quicksort(list, p + 1, h);              // Sort upper partition
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are sorting a random-accessible collection (like an array), it's general best to pick the physical middle item.  With this, if the array is all ready sorted (or nearly sorted), the two partitions will be close to even, and you'll get the best speed.

If you are sorting something with only linear access (like a linked-list), then it's best to choose the first item, because it's the fastest item to access.  Here, however,if the list is already sorted, you're screwed -- one partition will always be null, and the other have everything, producing the worst time.

However, for a linked-list, picking anything besides the first, will just make matters worse.  It pick the middle item in a listed-list, you'd have to step through it on each partition step -- adding a O(N/2) operation which is done logN times making total time O(1.5 N *log N) and that's if we know how long the list is before we start -- usually we don't so we'd have to step all the way through to count them, then step half-way through to find the middle, then step through a third time to do the actual partition: O(2.5N * log N)

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely dependent on how your data is sorted to begin with. If you think it will be pseudo-random then your best bet is to either pick a random selection or choose the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Its very depends on your specific needs and input source/specific.

> For any deterministic method of pivot selection, there exists a
> worst-case input instance which will doom us to quadratic time. We can
> add an initial step to our algorithm where we randomly permute the
> order of the n elements before we try to sort them. Such a permutation
> can be constructed in O(n) time. This might seem like wasted effort,
> but it provides the guarantee that we can expect Θ(n log n) running
> time whatever the initial input was. The worst case performance still
> can happen, but it now depends only upon how unlucky we are. There is
> no longer a well-defined “worst-case” input.

**(c) The Algorithm Design Manual 3rd edition**

Big thanks to Steven Skiena for this wonderful book <3

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the pivot should be the middle value in the entire array.
This will reduce the chances of getting worst case performance.

Comment: cart in front of horse here.

Answer (score 0):

In a truly optimized implementation, the method for choosing pivot should depend on the array size - for a large array, it pays off to spend more time choosing a good pivot. Without doing a full analysis, I would guess "middle of O(log(n)) elements" is a good start, and this has the added bonus of not requiring any extra memory: Using tail-call on the larger partition and in-place partitioning, we use the same O(log(n)) extra memory at almost every stage of the algorithm.

Comment: Finding the middle of 3 elements can be done in constant time .  Any more, and we essentially have to sort the  sub array.  As n becomes large, we run right back into the sorting problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Quick sort's complexity varies greatly with the selection of pivot value. for example if you always choose first element as an pivot, algorithm's complexity becomes as worst as O(n^2). here is an smart method to choose pivot element-
1. choose the first, mid, last element of the array.
2. compare these three numbers and find the number which is greater than one and smaller than other i.e. median.
3. make this element as pivot element.

choosing the pivot by this method splits the array in nearly two half and hence the complexity 
reduces to O(nlog(n)).

Answer (score 0):

On the average, Median of 3 is good for small n. Median of 5 is a bit better for larger n. The ninther, which is the "median of three medians of three" is even better for very large n.

The higher you go with sampling the better you get as n increases, but the improvement dramatically slows down as you increase the samples. And you incur the overhead of sampling and sorting samples.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the middle index, as it can be calculated easily.

You can calculate it by rounding (array.length / 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the first or the last element in the array, then there are high chance that the pivot is the smallest or the largest element of the array and that is bad.
*Why?*
**Because in that case the number of element smaller / larger than the pivot element in 0. and this will repeat as follow :**
Consider the size of the array n.Then,

```
(n) + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + ......+ 1 = O(n^2)
```

Hence, the time complexity increases to **O(n^2)** from O(nlogn). So, I highly recommend to use median / random element of the array as the pivot.