# Which sort algorithm works best on mostly sorted data?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Which sorting algorithm works best on mostly sorted data?

Comment: Guessing from lack of context - you are asking about an in-memory sort with no requirement to spill intermediate results to disk?

Comment: [According to these animations](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/nearly-sorted-initial-order) insertion sorting works best on mostly sorted data.

Answer (score 279):

Based on the highly scientific method of watching [animated gifs](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) I would say Insertion and Bubble sorts are good candidates.

Comment: that's an excellent link by the way, kudos and a +1

Comment: That link should be in every sorting question.  Thanks!

Comment: Bubble sort is terrible.  It is always O(n^2).  At least take that out of your answer for it to be right please.

Comment: jjnguy, that is just plain wrong.  I think you need to re-take your algorithms class.  On nearly sorted data (it's adaptive case) it is O(N).  However, it takes 2 passes through the data and Insertion only takes 1 for nearly sorted data, which makes Insertion the winner.  Bubble is still good though

Comment: Bubble sort only needs something like two passes for each unsorted element.  If the data truly only has a few unsorted elements, then bubble sort will be pretty snappy.

Comment: Performance degrades really badly if your data is ever not nearly sorted though. I would still not use it, personally.

Comment: It looks like Bubble > Shell > Merge > Heap. But Bubble and Shell appear to be front runners for mostly sorted data.

Comment: @Thomas Owens, Insertion > Bubble Or Shell for nearly sorted data.

Comment: That link was broken when I tried it.  Try this instead: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: +1 for the link, before I saw this I only knew about http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/SortVisualization.aspx

Comment: The actual answer is insertion sort. Bubble sort is never the answer. Just never

Comment: Bubble has specific use cases — it's great on embedded systems if the incoming data is almost sorted: it takes very little RAM (tiny code size and in-place sorting), and is extremely fast for just fixing lists containing just a few "almost in order" items.  My favourite sorting algo, merge, would still be burning up stack space by the time Bubble had run *twice* in a recent use case.

Comment: I love how that link goes to Toptal.

Comment: To be fair, O(n²) is technically a superset of O(n), so bubble sort is in O(n²).

Comment: I would use [bidirectional bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort) instead of plain bubble sort to prevent being terribly slowed down by small elements close to the end of the list, should a small number of elements have positions that are very far from where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 130):

Only a few items => INSERTION SORT

Items are mostly sorted already => INSERTION SORT

Concerned about worst-case scenarios => HEAP SORT

Interested in a good average-case result =>  QUICKSORT

Items are drawn from a dense universe  => BUCKET SORT

Desire to write as little code as possible =>  INSERTION SORT

Comment: That is exactly the kind of answer I have been looking for, I read books but I don't seem to find any clear explanation for selection of alogorithms at particular cases, could you please elaborate this or pass a link so that i can dog into it a little more? Thanks

Comment: You should add "Data is already sorted by another criterion => MERGE SORT"

Comment: @JimHunziker can you link where I can find an implementation of merge sort that exploits the pattern you mentioned? Or is it that just any normal merge sort does that without any change?

Comment: @python_learner because merge sort is a stable sort, items that have the same key in the new sort will remain sorted by the old sort. If, for example, you had a list sorted by first name, and then you merge sort by last name, the people with the last name Smith will remain sorted by their first names. This is true for all implementations of merge sort.

Answer (score 34):

### timsort

[Timsort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) is "an adaptive, stable, natural mergesort" with "**supernatural performance on many
kinds of partially ordered arrays** (less than lg(N!) comparisons needed, and
as few as N-1)".  Python's built-in `sort()` has used this algorithm for some time, apparently with good results.  It's specifically designed to detect and take advantage of partially sorted subsequences in the input, which often occur in real datasets.  It is often the case in the real world that comparisons are much more expensive than swapping items in a list, since one typically just swaps pointers, which very often makes timsort an excellent choice.  However, if you know that your comparisons are always very cheap (writing a toy program to sort 32-bit integers, for instance), other algorithms exist that are likely to perform better.  The easiest way to take advantage of timsort is of course to use Python, but since Python is open source you might also be able to borrow the code.  Alternately, the description above contains more than enough detail to write your own implementation.

Comment: log(n!) is Ο(n*log(n)) therefore It is not "supernatural".

Comment: Here's the Java implementation coming in JDK7: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~martin/webrevs/openjdk7/timsort/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/java/util/TimSort.java

Comment: log(n!) is not fast.
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot[log(N!),{N,0,1000}]

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: timsort is much faster than `lg(n!)` comparisons on an almost-sorted array, all the way down to `O(n)`! | @behrooz: No comparison sort can have an average case of better than `O(n log n)`, and `lg(n!)` is `O(n log n)`. So timsort's worst case is asymptotically no worse than that of any other comparison sort. Furthermore its best case is better than or equal to any other comparison sort.

Comment: Timsort is still O(nlogn) in the worst case, but its good-cases are quite pleasing.  Here's a comparison, with some graphs: http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/sort-comparison/  Note that timsort in Cython wasn't nearly as fast as Python's built in timsort in C.

Answer (score 21):

Insertion sort with the following behavior:

1. For each element `k` in slots `1..n`, first check whether `el[k] >= el[k-1]`.  If so, go to next element.  (Obviously skip the first element.)
2. If not, use binary-search in elements `1..k-1` to determine the insertion location, then scoot the elements over.  (You might do this only if `k>T` where `T` is some threshold value; with small `k` this is overkill.)

This method makes the least number of comparisons.

Comment: I think bubble sort might beat this if the number of unsorted elements is very small (like, one or two), but in general this strikes me as probably the best solution.

Comment: Because of step 1, for any elements that are already sorted there is exactly one compare and zero data-moves, which is obviously the best you can do.  Step 2 is the one you could improve on, but bubble will move the same number of elements and *might* have more compares, depending on your impl.

Comment: Actually, on further thought I think bubble sort is stronger than I was thinking.  It's actually a fairly tricky question.  For instance, if you take the case where the list is entirely sorted except the element which should be last is first, bubble sort will vastly outperform what you describe.

Comment: I tried to implement this but the binary search is not much of an improvement since you still have to move the entire block to insert the element. So instead of 2xrange you get range + logb(range).

Answer (score 12):

Try introspective sort. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort

It's quicksort based, but it avoids the worst case behaviour that quicksort has for nearly sorted lists.

The trick is that this sort-algorithm detects the cases where quicksort goes into worst-case mode and switches to heap or merge sort. Nearly sorted partitions are detected by some non naiive partition method and small partitions are handled using insertion sort.

**You get the best of all major sorting algorithms for the cost of a more code and complexity.** And you can be sure you'll never run into worst case behaviour no matter how your data looks like.

If you're a C++ programmer check your std::sort algorithm. It may already use introspective sort internally.

Answer (score 9):

[Splaysort](http://www.cs.mu.oz.au/~alistair/splaysort.c) is an obscure sorting method based on [splay trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree), a type of adaptive binary tree. Splaysort is good not only for partially sorted data, but also partially reverse-sorted data, or indeed any data that has any kind of pre-existing order.  It is O(nlogn) in the general case, and O(n) in the case where the data is sorted in some way (forward, reverse, organ-pipe, etc.).

Its great advantage over insertion sort is that it doesn't revert to O(n^2) behaviour when the data isn't sorted at all, so you don't need to be absolutely sure that the data is partially sorted before using it.

Its disadvantage is the extra space overhead of the splay tree structure it needs, as well as the time required to build and destroy the splay tree.  But depending on the size of data and amount of pre-sortedness that you expect, the overhead may be worth it for the increase in speed.

A [paper on splaysort](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=230594) was published in Software--Practice & Experience.

Answer (score 6):

insertion or shell sort!

Answer (score 6):

Dijkstra's smoothsort is a great sort on already-sorted data.  It's a heapsort variant that runs in O(n lg n) worst-case and O(n) best-case.  I [wrote an analysis](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort) of the algorithm, in case you're curious how it works.

Natural mergesort is another really good one for this - it's a bottom-up mergesort variant that works by treating the input as the concatenation of multiple different sorted ranges, then using the merge algorithm to join them together.  You repeat this process until all of the input range is sorted.  This runs in O(n) time if the data is already sorted and O(n lg n) worst-case.  It's very elegant, though in practice it isn't as good as some other adaptive sorts like Timsort or smoothsort.

Comment: what’s are the runtime constants of smoothsort compared to other sorting algorithms? (i.e. runtime(smoothsort) / runtime(insertionsort) for the same data)

Answer (score 5):

If elements are already sorted or there are only few elements, 
 it would be a perfect use case for Insertion Sort!

Answer (score 4):

Insertion sort takes time O(n + the number of inversions).

An inversion is a pair `(i, j)` such that `i < j && a[i] > a[j]`.  That is, an out-of-order pair.

One measure of being "almost sorted" is the number of inversions---one could take "almost sorted data" to mean data with few inversions.  If one knows the number of inversions to be linear (for instance, you have just appended O(1) elements to a sorted list), insertion sort takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 3):

As everyone else said, be careful of naive Quicksort - that can have O(N^2) performance on sorted or nearly sorted data.  Nevertheless, with an appropriate algorithm for choice of pivot (either random or median-of-three - see [Choosing a Pivot for Quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164163/choosing-a-pivot-for-quicksort)), Quicksort will still work sanely.

In general, the difficulty with choosing algorithms such as insert sort is in deciding when the data is sufficiently out of order that Quicksort really would be quicker.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to pretend to have all the answers here, because I think getting at the actual answers may require coding up the algorithms and profiling them against representative data samples.  But I've been thinking about this question all evening, and here's what's occurred to me so far, and some guesses about what works best where.

Let N be the number of items total, M be the number out-of-order.

Bubble sort will have to make something like 2*M+1 passes through all N items.  If M is very small (0, 1, 2?), I think this will be very hard to beat.

If M is small (say less than log N), insertion sort will have great average performance.  However, unless there's a trick I'm not seeing, it will have very bad worst case performance.  (Right?  If the last item in the order comes first, then you have to insert every single item, as far as I can see, which will kill the performance.)  I'm guessing there's a more reliable sorting algorithm out there for this case, but I don't know what it is.

If M is bigger (say equal or great than log N), introspective sort is almost certainly best.

Exception to all of that: If you actually know ahead of time which elements are unsorted, then your best bet will be to pull those items out, sort them using introspective sort, and merge the two sorted lists together into one sorted list.  If you could quickly figure out which items are out of order, this would be a good general solution as well -- but I haven't been able to figure out a simple way to do this.

Further thoughts (overnight): If M+1 < N/M, then you can scan the list looking for a run of N/M in a row which are sorted, and then expand that run in either direction to find the out-of-order items.  That will take at most 2N comparisons.  You can then sort the unsorted items, and do a sorted merge on the two lists.  Total comparisons should less than something like 4N+M log2(M), which is going to beat any non-specialized sorting routine, I think.  (Even further thought: this is trickier than I was thinking, but I still think it's reasonably possible.)

Another interpretation of the question is that there may be many of out-of-order items, but they are very close to where they should be in the list. (Imagine starting with a sorted list and swapping every other item with the one that comes after it.)  In that case I think bubble sort performs very well -- I think the number of passes will be proportional to the furthest out of place an item is.  Insertion sort will work poorly, because every out of order item will trigger an insertion.  I suspect introspective sort or something like that will work well, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in need of specific implementation for sorting algorithms, data structures or anything that have a link to the above, could I recommend you the excellent ["Data Structures and Algorithms"](http://www.codeplex.com/dsa) project on CodePlex?

It will have everything you need without reinventing the wheel.

Just my little grain of salt.

Answer (score 2):

This nice collection of sorting algorithms for this purpose in the answers, seems to lack [Gnome Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort), which would also be suitable, and probably requires the least implementation effort.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort is best case O(n) on sorted input.  And it is very close on mostly sorted input (better than quick sort).

Answer (score 0):

Bubble-sort (or, safer yet, bi-directional bubble sort) is likely ideal for mostly sorted lists, though I bet a tweaked comb-sort (with a much lower initial gap size) would be a little faster when the list wasn't quite as perfectly sorted.  Comb sort degrades to bubble-sort.

Answer (score 0):

well it depends on use case. If you know which elements is changed, remove and insert will be the best case as far as I am concerned.

Comment: This "as far as I am concerned" test of algorithm efficiency brightened up my day :)

Being serious, though, when writing "remove and insert" did you mean Insertion Sort (which was already mentioned in previous answers), or do you offer a new kind of algorithm? If so, please expand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort is definitely the winner
The next one on the radar would be insertion sort.

Comment: post your answer with an explanation;

Comment: I would suggest you have a look at the available answers before posting to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

*ponder* Try Heap. I believe it's the most consistent of the O(n lg n) sorts.

Comment: Consistency is not of concern here. Heapsort will give O(n lg n) even on sorted data, and is not really adaptive. Viable options can be: Insertion sort, Timsort and Bubblesort.

Answer (score -2):

Keep away from QuickSort - its very inefficient for pre-sorted data. Insertion sort handles almost sorted data well by moving as few values as possible.

Comment: -1 Every industrial implementation of Quicksort has a reasonable pivot selection

Comment: Yes, but no pivot selection is perfect unless it gets expensive.

Comment: Most industrial quicksorts I've seen just switch to insertion sort when there are fewer than 10 or 20 elements in the array chunk.