# If you had an array of Strings, what is the quickest way to sort this array in ascending order?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

If you had an array of Strings, what is the quickest way to sort this array in ascending order ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[])](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))

```
import java.util.*;
Arrays.sort(stringarray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays.sort() for now.

Also I heard that Josh Bloch is working on a much faster sort algorithm than the current mergesort. (I can't remember where, maybe in [this interview](http://parleys.com/display/PARLEYS/Home#title=Joshua%20Bloch%20Devoxx%20Interview;slide=1;talk=29098015). The new algorithm will perform better for partially sorted arrays and originates from a Python? sort implementation). Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data) question.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] Mystring = {"cat","lion", "dog", "mouse"};
Arrays.sort(Mystring);
```

[Sorting Arrays](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html)

Answer (score 1):

[`Arrays.sort(Object)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))

[`Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator))