# Custom javascript object sort and maintain index association

Tags: javascript, jquery

The object

```
var obj = {
   uniquestring1:
   {
       obj1: 'content',
       obj2: 'content'
   },
   uniquestring2:
   {
       obj1: 'content'
   }
}
```

So i need to sort the object by number of the elements contained by the first parent element. The use of .sort function is not a sollution for me because i need to maintain the index assosiaction which array's dont keep.

The result should be:

```
var obj = {
   uniquestring2:
   {
       obj1: 'content'
   },
   uniquestring1:
   {
       obj1: 'content',
       obj2: 'content'
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't sort an object's properties because they are not an ordered array. Perhaps you want to iterate over the properties in a certain order?

Comment: implement some sorting algorithm, don't use jquery .sort if it doesn't fit your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javscript objects don't have a sort order so they can't be sorted.  To sort, you must have an array somewhere and I see no array in your code.

Object keys have no defined order.

- If you only need ordered access, use an array.
- If you only need keyed access, use an object.
- If you need access by both, you can use a parallel array, but this is a pain unless the data is not changing.

You could do a one-time creation of a parallel array that contained key references in sorted order like this:

```
var obj = {
   uniquestring1:
   {
       obj1: 'content',
       obj2: 'content'
   },
   uniquestring2:
   {
       obj1: 'content'
   }
}

var objOrder = [];   // sorted arrays that contains first level keys into obj
var num;
for (var i in obj) {
    objOrder.push(i);  // get all keys into the array
    num = 0;
    for (var j in obj[i]) {
        ++num;         // count items in each key object
    }
    obj[i].keyCnt = num;   // save this for later sorting purposes
}
// now sort the parallel array by keyCnt
objOrder.sort(function(a, b) {
    return(obj[a].keyCnt - obj[b].keyCnt);
});
```

Then, to traverse the keys in sorted order, you would do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sortedOrder.length; i++ ) {
    var item = obj[sortedOrder[i]];
    // do something with item here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`obj` is a hash not an array, so you can't sort it. For example, `obj[0]; // is undefined`. Now if you had this:

```
var obj = {
   uniquestring1:
   {
       obj1: 'content',
       obj2: 'content'
   },
   uniquestring2:
   {
       obj1: 'content'
   }
};
var arr = [],

for(var i in obj) {
    arr.push(obj[i]);
}

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
   return Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length;
})
```

Then that sort would work, with [**Object.keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Of course i know that, that is why i've asked here for a workaround.

Comment: @keepwalking: why are you looking for a workaround? What's wrong with this? If you need your labels, you should wrap your objects in *yet another* object:
   {label: 'uniquestring1', value: {
       obj1: 'content',
       obj2: 'content'
   }

Comment: Keep in mind the the `.keys()` property of an object is not supported in older browsers such as IE6-IE8.