# Sorting algorithm for sorted vectors of "moving" values

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This question is related to [Which sort algorithm works best on mostly sorted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data)

The difference is that I have other very important restriction: **the values are changed with small amounts after every sort.**

This means that the vector stays almost sorted and the displaced values are nearly in their position. After making some tests it seems same answer apply for my case.

Do you know other algorithms that may be better in this case?

Comment: Could you characterize "changed with small amounts" a bit more? Are they affine changes, random changes, or something else? There are efficient ways if for example every point has a fixed linear velocity.

Comment: @Nabb The points don't have fixed, nor linear velocity, but if the values are in [-100 , 100] range, the amount of change between sorting is in [-0.05, 0.05] range for every point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider timsort or smoothsort. These are designed with mostly-sorted data in mind.

Answer (score 0):

If frequent update is the case, maintain an index structure (i.e. a binary search tree) is perhaps a better choice than sorting the vector over and over again.

Comment: I need to have the vector sorted to speed up other operations.

Comment: Is it mandatory in your application that the elements of the vector be sorted and sequential in the physical memory layout? or perhaps a sorted representation ensuring O(n) traversal would be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Insertion-Sort and Bubble-Sort both have linear best case complexity for an input, which is already sorted (which is optimal since the values are continuously changing, i.e. you have to have a look at each element of the input vector) and they are stable (which seems to be a useful property given your problem description).

Answer (score 0):

Compare all the pairs a[i] <= a[i+1]. If this is false, move the second element to a new array.

Sort the new array (mergesort, heapsort or any other O(n*log n) algorithm), and merge the new and old array again.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Def CheckedMergeSort(L)

    Count = 0
    S(1) = 0

    For I in 2 to |L|
       If (L(I-1) < L(I))
           Count = Count + 1
           S(I) = Count

    Def MergeSort(A, B)
        If (A != B and S(B)-S(A) != B-A)
            C = (B + A) / 2
            MergeSort(A,C)
            MergeSort(C+1,B)
            InplaceMerge(L(A..C), L(C+1..B))

    MergeSort(1, |L|)
```

A linear time prepass of the input is made to fill in S(i) which keeps track of how many pairs previous to i have been in sorted order.

Then by subtracting two bounds S(j)-S(i) and comparing it to j-1 we can determine if any subsequence L(i..j) is in sorted order.

The merge sort then can skip any sorted sequences it finds in its recursion in constant time.

(For example if the array is sorted at entry then MergeSort(1, |L|) becomes a noop.)