# Best sorting algorithm for a partly sorted sequence?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time, complexity-theory

I have to answer the following question:

What sorting algorithm is recommended if the first n-m part
is already sorted and the remaining part m is unsorted? Are there any algorithms that take O(n log m) comparisons?  What about O(m log n) comparisons?

I just can't find the solution.

My first idea was insertion sort because O(n) for almost sorted sequence. But since we don't know the size of m the Runtime is very likely to be O(n^2) eventough the sequence is half sorted already isn't it?

Then I tought perhabs its quick sort because it takes (Sum from k=1 to n) Cavg (1-m) + Cavg (n-m) comparisons. But after ignoring the n-m part of the sequence the remaining sequence is 1-m in quicksort and not m.

Merge Sort and heap sort should have a runtime of O(m log m) for the remaining sequence m I would say.

Does anyone have an idea or can give me some advice?

Greetings

Comment: Because this is a pure algorithmic question, it may better suit [cs.se] (but remember to read their help center before asking) / Besides, it's impossible to get less than the time for reading the sequence which is already O(n).

Comment: If you know which part is sorted, sort only the rest and than merge the two sorted parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried **sorting remaining part `m` separately** as `O(m log (m))` complexity (with any algorithm you like: MergeSort, HeapSort, QuickSort, ...) and then **merge** that part with sorted part using [MergeSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) (You won't even need to fully implement MergeSort - just single pass of it's inner loop body to merge two sorted sequences)?

That would result in `O(m*log(m) + n + m) = O(m*log(m) + n)` complexity. I don't believe it is possible to find better asymptotic complexity on single-core CPU. Although it will require additional `O(n+m)` memory for merging result array.

Comment: Remark: *QuickSort* is in worst case **O(n²)** not O(n log n).

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Use binary search instead of linear scan to find the merge positions of the final **m** items.  Then number of comparisons is **O(m log mn)**

Comment: @MattTimmermans, How should binary search help? You still need to insert those elements somehow. And inserting in the middle of array will require shifting all remaining items.

Comment: Yes.  I expect that's why the OP specifically asked about the number of comparisons

Answer (score 0):

[Which sort algorithm works best on mostly sorted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220044/which-sort-algorithm-works-best-on-mostly-sorted-data)

Sounds like insertion and bubble are good. You are free to implement as many as you want then test to see which is faster/fewer operations by supplying them partially sorted data.