# Explanation of the Median of Medians algorithm

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, median, median-of-medians

The `Median of medians` approach is very popular in `quicksort` type partitioning algorithms to yield a fairly good pivot, such that it partitions the array uniformly. Its logic is given in Wikipedia as:

> The chosen pivot is both less than and greater than half of the elements in the list of medians, which is around n/10 elements (1/2 * (n/5)) for each half. Each of these elements is a median of 5, making it less than 2 other elements and greater than 2 other elements outside the block. Hence, the pivot is less than 3(n/10) elements outside the block, and greater than another 3(n/10) elements outside the block. Thus the chosen median splits the elements somewhere between 30%/70% and 70%/30%, which assures worst-case linear behavior of the algorithm.

Can somebody explain it a bit lucidly for me. I am finding it difficult to understand the logic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Think of the following set of numbers:

```
5 2 6 3 1
```

The median of these numbers is `3`. Now if you have a number `n`, if `n > 3`, then it is bigger than at least half of the numbers above. If `n < 3`, then it is smaller than at least half of the numbers above.

So that is the idea. That is, for each set of 5 numbers, you get their median. Now you have `n / 5` numbers. This is obvious.

Now if you get the median of those numbers (call it `m`), it is bigger than half of them and smaller than the other half (by definition of median!). In other words, `m` is bigger than `n / 10` numbers (which themselves were medians of small 5 element groups) and bigger than another `n / 10` numbers (which again were medians of small 5 element groups).

In the example above, we saw that if the median is `k` and you have `m > k`, then `m` is also bigger than 2 other numbers (that were themselves smaller than `k`). This means that for each of those smaller 5 element groups where `m` was bigger than its median, `m` is also bigger than two other numbers. This makes it at least 3 numbers (2 numbers + the median itself) in each of those `n / 10` small 5 element groups, that are smaller than `m`. Hence, `m` is at least bigger than `3n/10` numbers.

Similar logic for the number of elements `m` is bigger than.

Comment: Just another question, how does this method guarantee that this number will be the median? The median is a number which partitions the array into the upper and lower half. So what does this 30-30-70 figure signify?

Comment: Well, the median is in the middle, but `m` (in the text above) is not the median of all numbers. It is the median of only 1/5 of the numbers (which are themselves medians of smaller 5 element groups). Try reading the last paragraph with more attention. In the end, where it is concluded that `m` is bigger than at least `3n/10` of the numbers, well that translates to `m` is bigger than at least 30% of the numbers. So in the end, it goes like `m` is bigger than at least 30% and smaller than at least another 30%. There is 40% left which we are not sure of.

Comment: Then how come it gives a 50-50 partition on average? The 50-50 partition is given by the normal median, right?

Comment: It doesn't give `50-50` partition on average. It always gives somewhere between `30-70` and `70-30` (maybe you could call that `50-50` on average?), but that's not the point. For quicksort to give `O(nlogn)` time complexity, it needs to be able to divide the array into partitions proportional to the size of the array. That's what gives the `logn` recursion depth. `30-70` division already gives a `3n/10` and `7n/10` division which is proportional to `n`. So even though it's not a perfect `50-50`, it will still yield logarithmic recursion depth (except it's not `log` in base 2, but base `10/7`)