# tukey's ninther for different shufflings of same data

Tags: java, algorithm, median-of-medians

While implementing improvements to quicksort partitioning,I tried to use Tukey's ninther to find the pivot (borrowing almost everything from sedgewick's implementation in [QuickX.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/23quicksort/QuickX.java.html))

My code below gives different results each time the array of integers is shuffled.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class TukeysNintherDemo{    
    public static int tukeysNinther(Comparable[] a,int lo,int hi){
        int N = hi - lo + 1;
        int mid = lo + N/2;
        int delta = N/8;
        int m1 = median3a(a,lo,lo+delta,lo+2*delta);
        int m2 = median3a(a,mid-delta,mid,mid+delta);
        int m3 = median3a(a,hi-2*delta,hi-delta,hi);
        int tn = median3a(a,m1,m2,m3);
        return tn;
    }

    // return the index of the median element among a[i], a[j], and a[k]
    private static int median3a(Comparable[] a, int i, int j, int k) {
        return (less(a[i], a[j]) ?
               (less(a[j], a[k]) ? j : less(a[i], a[k]) ? k : i) :
               (less(a[k], a[j]) ? j : less(a[k], a[i]) ? k : i));
    }

    private static boolean less(Comparable x,Comparable y){
        return x.compareTo(y) < 0;
    }
    public static void shuffle(Object[] a) {
    Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        int N = a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int r = i + random.nextInt(N-i);     // between i and N-1
            Object temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[r];
            a[r] = temp;
        }
    }
    public static void show(Comparable[] a){    
        int N = a.length;
        if(N > 20){
            System.out.format("a[0]= %d\n", a[0]);
            System.out.format("a[%d]= %d\n",N-1, a[N-1]);
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
                System.out.print(a[i]+",");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] a = new Integer[]{17,15,14,13,19,12,11,16,18};
        System.out.print("data= ");
        show(a);
        int tn = tukeysNinther(a,0,a.length-1);
        System.out.println("ninther="+a[tn]);
    }
}

Running this a cuople of times gives

data= 11,14,12,16,18,19,17,15,13,
ninther=15

data= 14,13,17,16,18,19,11,15,12,
ninther=14

data= 16,17,12,19,18,13,14,11,15,
ninther=16
```

Will tuckey's ninther give different values for different shufflings of the same dataset? when I tried to find the median of medians by hand ,I found that the above calculations in the code are correct.. which means that the same dataset yield different results unlike a median of the dataset.Is this the proper behaviour? Can someone with more knowledge in statistics comment?

Comment: A sorted array is a sorted array. If you shuffle data then sort it you should always end up with the same data. The Median is the middle value; in the same data it should also always be the same. Just like the Mean or Mode. Maybe look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545795/explanation-of-the-median-of-medians-algorithm) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489061/understanding-median-of-medians-algorithm).

Comment: On another note; I suppose this is some sort of exercise or test? Because Java has perfectly good methods in [`Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) and [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to do many of the things you have coded yourself here. `Arrays.toString`, `Collections.shuffle` and, of course, `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: I am trying to learn some algorithms stuff ..not trying to solve any problem using java library..

Comment: your logic for median will work only on sorted array.

Comment: median3a() compares all the three elements to get the median.. doesn't need sorted array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tukey's ninther examines 9 items and calculates the median using *only* those.

For different random shuffles, you may very well get a different Tukey's ninther, because different items may be examined. After all, you always examine the same array slots, but a different shuffle may have put different items in those slots.

The key here is that Tukey's ninther is **not the median of the given array**. It is an attempted appromixation of the median, made with very little effort: we only have to read 9 items and make 12 comparisons to get it. This is much faster than getting the actual median, and has a smaller chance of resulting in an undesirable pivot compared to the 'median of three'. Note that the chance still exists.

Does this answer you question?

On a side note, does anybody know if quicksort using Tukey's ninther still requires shuffling? I'm assuming yes, but I'm not certain.

Comment: I just realize that deterministic (i.e. *non*-shuffled) quicksort using Tukey's ninther is, of course, vulnerable to malicious input. So shuffling is indeed required.