# Quicksort and pivot randomization

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, quicksort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quicksort: Choosing the pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164163/quicksort-choosing-the-pivot)

I read a statement:

> The performance of quicksort falls on already sorted/almost sorted
>   lists if the pivot is not randomized.

Please help explain this.
I would have expected more comparisons probably  - but not more swaps.
I thought the worst case of a quick sort was sorting an inverted array.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a sequence of numbers like {29, 24, 20, 19, 16, ...}  an algorithm that discovers that it is a monotonically decreasing sequence and if we want an ascending sort simply reverses the sequence is more efficiently.