# Python Quicksort Runtime Error: Maximum Recursion Depth Exceeded in cmp

Tags: python, recursion, runtime-error, quicksort

I'm writing a program that will read a text file containing 5,163 names. (text file can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/BAKTJKy6))

Then I want to store the names into a list called 'names', afterwards, I sort the list based on how many letters the name contains, shorter names are at the start of the list and the longer ones are at the end.

I used quicksort to sort the list, but when I run it, it shows this error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 25, in <module>
    names = quicksort(names)
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 8, in quicksort
    greater = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if not lessThan(x, pivot)])
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 7, in quicksort
    lesser = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if lessThan(x, pivot)])
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 8, in quicksort
    greater = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if not lessThan(x, pivot)])
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 7, in quicksort
    lesser = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if lessThan(x, pivot)])
# [.... many lines elided ...]
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 8, in quicksort
    greater = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if not lessThan(x, pivot)])
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 8, in quicksort
    greater = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if not lessThan(x, pivot)])
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 7, in quicksort
    lesser = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if lessThan(x, pivot)])
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/Desktop/Anagrams/Main.py", line 3, in quicksort
    if list == []:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp
```

The full traceback is available [as a pastie](http://pastebin.com/cC671BTd).

I've tested the quicksort function and it works for ordinary lists (ex: list = ['Alice','Bob,'Carl','Derp']), but it doesn't work if I try to sort 'names'

Here's my code

```
def quicksort(list):
    """Quicksort using list comprehensions"""
    if list == []:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = list[0]
        lesser = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if lessThan(x, pivot)])
        greater = quicksort([x for x in list[1:] if not lessThan(x, pivot)])
        return lesser + [pivot] + greater

def lessThan(a, b):
    return len(a) < len(b)

#'''
input = open('Names.txt', 'r')
output = open('Names Arranged By Length.txt', 'w')

names = []

for line in input:
    line = line.translate(None, '\n')
    names.append(line)


names = quicksort(names)

for i in names:
    print i
    output.write(i)
    output.write('\n')

print 'Count: ', len(names)


input.close()
output.close()
#'''
```

What's wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is `len(names)`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, I know what `len(names)` does! I mean: how long is the list of names?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: ah, I see what you mean; you want to know how deep the rabbit hole goes to produce that kind of stack trace.

Comment: jonrsharpe is correct: you are probably trying to sort **too large a list**.

Comment: Do you *have* to use Quicksort? Because the built-in sort is far superior to Quicksort, and you won't need to adjust it to avoid hitting the Python recursion limits.

Comment: The list contains 5,163 names, so len(names) should be 5,163 (if I didn't make a mistake that is)

Comment: no I don't have to use quicksort, but I don't know how to modify the method of comparison if I use the built-in sort method

Comment: Set e.g. `key=len` - see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have simply hit the recursion limits. Your list of names is too large for Python's limited recursion capabilities. Your Quicksort works just fine otherwise.

You *could* raise the recursion limit by setting the limit higher with [`sys.setrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit).   You can set it a fair amount higher, but you do so at your own risk.

A better option is to use the built-in Python sort; the [TimSort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) is far superior and won't hit a recursion limit:

```
names = sorted(names, key=len)
```

This sorts the names by their length, shortest names first.

Comment: What is a sane value for [`sys.setrecursionlimit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit)?

Comment: @dhill: The default is sane. If you need to raise it, think long and hard about the algorithm, perhaps it can be solved without recursion instead?

Answer (score 10):

You exceed python default recursion size. The default recursion limit is 1000. You can increase recursion limit but it is not recommended. Here is how to do

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

**Suggestion**

My suggestion is use [numpy.argsort()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) method which is already prepared for many sorting algorithms. [Here is simple examle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36592205/4104008)  for how to do quicksort algorith by using numpy library.