# could I do a quicksort algorithm based on this code for partitioning?

Tags: python-2.7, computer-science

```
def quicksort(A):
    a = A.pop(len(A)-1)
    c = []
    g = []
    for b in range(len(A)):
        if A[b] > a:
            c += [A[b]]
        else:
            g += [A[b]]
    A = g
    A += [a]
    A += c
    m = len(g)
    return A
```

this code does the partitioning, could I make a quick sort algorithm by adding something to it or doing some recursive calls

Comment: I am sorry that It's written like this I don't know why this happened.thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262384/4954037 shows quicksort in python. just in case.