# Sorting edges in a graph

Tags: python, graph

I have a `class` called `Graph` to represent a connected undirected graph, I want to implement quicksort to sort the edges based on weights on the edges.

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.vertices = range(n)
        self.edges = set([(random.random(), i, j) for i in xrange(n) for j in xrange(n)])

    def qsort(self):
        if len(self.edges) <= 1:
            return self.edges
        else:
            return qsort([x for x in self.edges[1:] if x < self.edges[0]]) + [self.edges[0]] + qsort([x for x in self.edges[1:] if x >= self.edges[0]])

graph = Graph(10)
graph.qsort()
```

When I try to run the above, I get `NameError: global name 'qsort' is not defined`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal answer to your question is that you are omitting the `self` keyword: `return self.qsort(...) + [self.edges[0]] + self.qsort(...)`.

It looks like you are trying to implement something like the 3-line qsort from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20258416/2988730), also given in the [Python Cookbook](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch02s12.html). Your implementation is wrong because it should take two arguments, `self` and the array you are sorting.

Unfortunately, there is no way to avoid passing in the array, but there is a possible workaround. Add an extra keyword argument to your method: `qsort(self, arr = None)`, then check if the array is `None` and use `self.edges` in that case. Your neat syntax of `graph.qsort()` will not have to change in that case:

```
def qsort(self, arr = None):
    if arr is None: arr = list(self.edges)
    if len(arr) <= 1: return arr
    else:
        return self.qsort([x for x in arr[1:] if x < arr[0]]) + \
               [arr[0]] + \
               self.qsort([x for x in arr[1:] if x >= arr[0]])
```

Note that because `self.edges` is a set, the qsort method is basically a no-op unless you do something with the output array. The set will not be altered.

Comment: It looks like 2 different sort are involved. self.sort() in the sample code doesn't accept any parameters. But the call to the missing "global" qsort() passes some ...

Comment: Good call. I have addressed the issue

Comment: I have added `self.qsort(...) + ...`. But now it says: `TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: You are getting the error because `self.edges` is a set, not a list or other iterable. I have updated the answer.