# Apply Quicksort to the list M,E,R,G,E,S,O,R,T

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

[image]I have been trying to analyse the operation of **Quicksort** for the above input. But i dont know what to do when i encounter **2 equal elements** while **traversing the list**. Could somebody help me with trace as how quick sort works for above input?   FIRST ELEMENT SHOULD BE PIVOT

Comment: do the same thing with them? i.e. move them to the same partition

Comment: I could not trace the quicksort operation for this. Every time try , i get it wrong.Kindly help.

Comment: Do you already have some code we can take a look at? If yes, please post it. Where exactly is the problem? Can you be a bit more precise please? For example show us the process until the point where you stuck.

Comment: there are 2 R's in this list. when variable i points to R and so does j , i dont know whether to exchange or not . By tracing i mean the way it is shown in anany levitin textbook. when i try to trace the algorithm for given input im not able to get it right.

Comment: @PradeepKumar If you're pivoting around `R`, and there is another `R` in the partitions on either side, then you can put the non-pivot `R` in either partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding quicksort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39665299/understanding-quicksort)

Answer (score 1):

Using `^` below a letter to indicate it's a pivot, and `*` to indicate it's already been pivoted. If a partition has odd length, I pick the "rounded down middle" (partition length 4 would have the 2nd item as pivot).

Note how in the 4th line, there are two `R`'s, with one of them being the pivot. In cases like this, the duplicate (the other `R`) can go on either side.

Edit: when comparing two letters, you need to sort them based on their **position in the alphabet**. If you "sort" based on their relative positions, you're never going to move any elements so naturally you'll never sort the list.

Edit #2: The algorithm I'm using is, unsurprisingly, [**quicksort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm).

```
MERGESORT -> EEMRGSORT
    ^         ^

EEMRGSORT -> EEMRGORST
^*   ^       ^*     ^

EEMRGORST -> EEGMRORST
**  ^  *^    **^    **

EEGMRORST -> EEGMORRST
*** ^  **    ***  ^ **

EEGMORRST -> EEGMORRST
***^ *^**    ***^ *^**

EEGMORRST -> EEGMORRST
****^****    ****^****

EEGMORRST -> Complete
*********
```

If I've made a mistake, please correct me.

Comment: could you please show me the trace for FIRST ELEMENT AS PIVOT. i had mentioned it earlier but my question was edited out

Comment: @PradeepKumar No. It took me long enough to do this example, which  highlights all the edge cases I can think of. If you can't extrapolate out from this trace where you're going wrong, then I can't help you.

Comment: Im sorry. i dint understand the first line itself as to how got EEMRGSORT.

Comment: @PradeepKumar Having selected `E` as the pivot (as it's in the middle, so for you you'd pick `M`), iterate over every other character in the partition that you picked the pivot from (here the entire string), and if an item is less than the pivot place it on the left, otherwise place it on the right.
So `M`>`E`, so we move `M` to the right of `E`. Then `E` = `E`, so we leave it. `R`>`E`, so we move `R` to the right of `E`.

Comment: Plz forgive me , im unable to follow u.I tried like u. taking middle E as pivot. M E R G are all less than E, so they will remain on left. S O R T are all greater than E. so they will remain right. No exchanges takes place. Howd u get EEMRGSORT?

Comment: @PradeepKumar No, all of MRGSORT come **later in the alphabet** than E. They're greater  in that sense.

Comment: Could u plz tell which algorithm you are using.could u give me the algorithm snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149613/discussion-between-pradeep-kumar-and-hnefatl).

Comment: Thanks a lot. U made me understand it easily.+1. Thank u