# How to quicksort a nested list.

Tags: python, list, nested, quicksort

I'm not sure how to implement the quicksort algorithm into a nested list. If I have a list like this:

```
L = [['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]
```

and I want to order it based on the last number in each sublist.

Output:

```
final = [['Henry', '1', '5'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1']]
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: All I've been able to do is using the sort function which works. But I wanted to try the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: Then please make a try first. Come with issues.

Comment: I'd suggest you try to implement the quicksort algorithm on a simple list first. Once you've gotten the concept, the alteration to the comparison should be quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I find an algorithm implementation from this question [Quicksort with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262306/quicksort-with-python). And just redefine the comparison funciton:

```
L = [['James', '1', '2'], ['Alan', '1', '1'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]

less_than = lambda x, y: x[2] < y[2]
more_than = lambda x, y: x[2] >= y[2]

def qsort(arr):
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        return arr
    else:
        return qsort([x for x in arr[1:] if less_than(x, arr[0])]) + [arr[0]] + qsort([x for x in arr[1:] if more_than(x, arr[0])])


print(qsort(L))
```

Output:

```
[['Alan', '1', '1'], ['James', '1', '2'], ['Henry', '1', '5']]
```

Hope this helps.