# List index out of range

Tags: python, list

I was implementing quicksort in python

```
#QuickSort python

def sort(array):

    leftside = []
    rightside = []
    equal = []

    pivot = array[0]

    if (len(array)>1):
        for item in array:
            if item < pivot:
                leftside.append(item)
            if item > pivot:
                rightside.append(item)
            if item == pivot:
                equal.append(item)
    else:
        print array


    print sort(leftside) + equal + sort(rightside)

array = [1,2,5,4,6,2,3]
sort(array)
```

I get the error 
  "pivot = array[0]
IndexError: list index out of range",  I don't see anything that could cause out of index error in this code. Could you please take a look?

Comment: It's the recursive call that eventually passes an empty list to sort and, naturally, `pivot = array[0]` chokes on it...

Comment: compare to http://stackoverflow.com/a/18262384/1248974

Comment: this is duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262306/quicksort-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pivot = array[0]` should be in `if (len(array)>1):`. Otherwise you may try to do it on an empty array.

Made some other quick fixes. See how this works:

```
#QuickSort python

def sort(array):

    leftside = []
    rightside = []
    equal = []

    if (len(array)>1):
        pivot = array[0]
        for item in array:
            if item < pivot:
                leftside.append(item)
            if item > pivot:
                rightside.append(item)
            if item == pivot:
                equal.append(item)
        return sort(leftside) + equal + sort(rightside)
    else:
        return array


array = [1,2,5,4,6,2,3]
print(sort(array))
```

Comment: Ah, Thanks for the answer. But, when I do that, I get "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".

Comment: @tori Yes, I realized that -- tried to fix some other issues for you. Please refer to something like http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html to see how others write quicksort in Python