# Python quicksort TypeError

Tags: python, sorting, typeerror, quicksort

Following are the errors that my code throws:

```
 File "python", line 39, in <module>
  File "python", line 8, in quicksort
  File "python", line 8, in quicksort
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Below is my code for quicksort:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def quicksort(arr, beg, end):
    if beg < end:
        pivot = partition(arr, beg, end)
        quicksort(arr, beg, pivot - 1)
        quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, end)

def partition(arr, beg, end):
    left = beg
    right = end
    loc = beg
    while arr[loc] <= arr[right] and loc != right:
        right = right - 1
    if loc == right:
        return loc
    elif arr[loc] > arr[right]:
        (arr[loc], arr[right]) = (arr[right], arr[loc])
        loc = right

    while arr[loc] >= arr[left] and loc != left:
        left = left + 1
    if loc == left:
        return loc
    elif arr[loc] < arr[left]:
        (arr[loc], arr[left]) = (arr[left], arr[loc])
        loc = left

y = [9,7,5,1,5]
quicksort(y, 0, 4)
print(y)
```

Comment: Somewhere you got a variable that is of `NoneType` (wich means it is `None`) and you are trying to subtract an `int` from it. Most probable culprit is `partition(..)` which seems to return `None` in some cases. `None` is returned by all functions that do not return something explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't subtract 2 variables from **[different types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11328920/1918287)** (`None` and `int`).
You got `None` because not all paths of `partition` function return something.
I added a `return` statement at the end of it which to me makes most sense:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

def quicksort(arr, beg, end):
    if beg < end:
        pivot = partition(arr, beg, end)
        quicksort(arr, beg, pivot - 1)
        quicksort(arr, pivot + 1, end)

def partition(arr, beg, end):
    left = beg
    right = end
    loc = beg
    while arr[loc] <= arr[right] and loc != right:
        right = right - 1
    if loc == right:
        return loc
    elif arr[loc] > arr[right]:
        (arr[loc], arr[right]) = (arr[right], arr[loc])
        loc = right

    while arr[loc] >= arr[left] and loc != left:
        left = left + 1
    if loc == left:
        return loc
    elif arr[loc] < arr[left]:
        (arr[loc], arr[left]) = (arr[left], arr[loc])
        loc = left

    return loc


y = [9,7,5,1,5]
quicksort(y, 0, 4)
print(y)  # >>> [1, 5, 5, 7, 9]
```

However, I did not check the correctness of your code's logic for each scenario.
You can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18262306/1918287) to see implementations of quicksort in python.

Answer (score 1):

From the function `partition` you are not returning anything. And you have assigned that to `pivot` variable. That is what the issue is. Look after the value you are supposed to return.