# I have a recursion limit error in my quick sort program although I set recursion limit to 1500

Tags: python, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to write an in-place program that would use the quicksort algorithm to sort a list. But it keeps giving an error:

> maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling python object.

Although I tried setting recursion limit.

```
def partition(L,low,high,comparison):
    i=low-1
    pivot=random_pivot(L)
    for j in range(low,high):
        if comparison(L[j],pivot):
            i+=1
            L[i],L[j]=L[j],L[i]
    L[i+1],L[high]=L[high],L[i+1]
    return i+1
def inplace_Quicksort(L,low,high,comparison):
    low=0
    high=len(L)-1
    if comparison(low,high):
        pivot_index=partition(L,low,high,comparison)
        inplace_Quicksort(L,low,pivot_index-1,comparison)
        inplace_Quicksort(L,pivot_index+1,high,comparison)
    print(L)
```

Can you please have a look at it and explain to me what is wrong? Thank you so much.

Comment: Try to debug your code yourself to see why the code recurses infinitely many times.

Comment: Please be so good to not destroy the constructive edits made by others.

Comment: What is `random_pivot`, and why do the arguments involve no range information?

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the range to the complete list each time you call `inplace_Quicksort` in the first two lines of its code, thereby making the arguments `low` and `high` useless.

This leads to an endless recursion. No increase of maximum recursion depth will help you.

Instead give your arguments a default value. Look how it is done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27461889/5459839).