# Need help wrapping my head around a type of implementation of quicksort

Tags: python, python-3.x, quicksort

I'm pretty new to python, and have been trying to self teach myself. Since I found out about sorting algorithms, I've been trying to wrap my head around them, specifically quicksort. I found an implementation of quicksort on stackoverflow, but have been very confused by one part in particular.

How does "return quicksort(lesser)+equal+quicksort(greater)" work exactly? If quicksort() is being called recursively, then wouldn't the lesser, equal, and greater arrays always be cleared on the initialization of the function every time? How exactly does python remember the organized array? How does python know to stop this recursion?

source of code: [Quicksort with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18262306/quicksort-with-python)

```py
def quicksort(array):
    lesser = []
    equal = []
    greater = []

    if len(array) > 1:
        p = array[0]
        for x in array:
            if x < p:
                lesser.append(x)
            elif x == p:
                equal.append(x)
            elif x > p:
                greater.append(x)

        return quicksort(lesser)+equal+quicksort(greater) # ???

    else:
        return array
```

Comment: Each level of recursion has its own private `lesser`, `equal`, and `greater` lists.  The recursion stops because of the `len(array) > 1` check - `lesser` and `greater` are at least one element shorter than the input list, so at some level their length drops below 2.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that almost the entire array ends up in the local arrays for many levels of recursion, except for the equal array which is not passed along to a deeper level of recursion. To clarify this statement, multiple instances of the function will be called each level of recursion, and most of those levels will consume stack space equal to nearly the size of the original array, except for the deepest levels of recursion where the local arrays will only hold a fraction of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

The function creates 3 new arrays every time it is called.  Although they have the same name, they are actually distinct because a recursive call places all the local data of the function on the stack (not just the parameters).

So, the 3 arrays from the previous call are not lost when the function calls itself.

Answer (score 1):

The recursion is creating new instances of the function, including variables, in memory (the *stack frame*). It is correct that these lists are cleared by the function, but not in the initial instance. The function sprouts new branches, recursively, and will only close the initial instance once the succeeding instance(s) have finished, closed, and returned their contribution.