# Ruby: comparison of String with String failed (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, string, sorting, comparison

Here is my ruby code:

```
books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]

books.sort! {

  |firstBook, secondBook|
  boolean_value = firstBook <=> secondBook
  print "first book is =  '#{firstBook}'"
  print " , second book is = '#{secondBook}'"
  puts  " and there compare result is #{boolean_value}"

}
```

**Questions:**

1. This code runs single iteration and then it gives error `in 'sort!': comparison of String with String failed (ArgumentError)`
2. When **firstbook =  "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory"** then **secondBook should be  "War and Peace"** but it code chooses **"Utopia" to compare. Why?**

Comment: 1. Array#sort! expect the block to return a number, your last statement puts return nil instead.
2. My guess is that Array#sort! use quicksort to compare, so "Utopia" is chosen as the pivot

Comment: I got this error when I used 'sort' on an array that unintentionally had mixed string and integer values.   The string values were strings of integers, so suffixing ".to_i" on the string array elements when they were initialized solved the problem.  No other StackOverflow question seems to address this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you return the comparison result from the block you passed to `sort!`.

Currently, you return `nil` (the return value of the last statement, the `puts`) and this leads to unpredictable results.

Change your code to:

```
books = ["Charlie and the Chocolate Factory", "War and Peace", "Utopia", "A Brief History of Time", "A Wrinkle in Time"]

books.sort! {

  |firstBook, secondBook|
  boolean_value = firstBook <=> secondBook
  print "first book is =  '#{firstBook}'"
  print " , second book is = '#{secondBook}'"
  puts  " and there compare result is #{boolean_value}"

  boolean_value  # <--- this line has been added
}
```

and everything will work.

---

Offtopic, a few nitpicks:

- in Ruby, the convention is to separate words with underscore in variable names. For example, you should rename `firstBook` -> `first_book`
- you should be very careful when naming variables. The variable `boolean_value` is a bit misleading here, because it's not `true` or `false`, its `-1`, `0`, or `1`.

Comment: Superb. Thanks for valuable advice.But why it chose "utopia" to compare as second book.

Comment: @paul I don't know exactly, but if I were to take a wild guess, I'd say that Ruby is using QuickSort under the cover, and *Utopia* is chosen as the quicksort pivot. [Apparently the middle element is a reasonable candidate for the pivot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/164177/390819).