# Storing pairwise sums in linear space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

If we have two arrays of size n each and want to sort their sums, the naive approach would be to store their sums in O(n^2) space and sort it in O(n^2 logn) time. Suppose we're allowed to have the same running time of O(n^2 logn), how would we store the sums in linear space of O(n)?

I suppose we're not intending to store all the sums since they n^2 elements won't fit into n space and that we're merely printing out everything in sorted order, so does this mean that we have to dynamically store the items? Any tips?

(this is a homework problem)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "sums of two arrays"? Please provide an example with expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: If we have 1 2 3 4 5 and 2 3 4 5 6, then the sums would be 3 4 5 6 7 4 5 6 7 8 5 6 7 8 9 6 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, as I understand it, is that we want to find the sums

```
a1 + b1  a1 + b2  ...  a1 + bn
a2 + b1  a2 + b2  ...  a2 + bn
  ...      ...    ...    ...
an + b1  an + b2  ...  an + bn
```

and print them in sorted order.
The restriction is to use only O (n) memory and O (n^2 log n) time in the process.

Consider the above table as `n` lists (lines) of `n` elements each.
If we sort the initial arrays so that `a1 <= a2 <= ... <= an` and `b1 <= b2 <= ... <= bn`, each list is already sorted.
Now, the problem is reduced to merging `n` sorted lists.

To devise that, think of how to merge two sorted lists (as in MergeSort), then three lists, and so on.
This extends trivially to merging `n` lists of length `n` each in `n` operations for each output element, for a total of `O (n^3)`.
Now, what's left is to reduce time for getting each output element down to `O (log n)`.
As you ask for a hint but not a complete solution, see if you can handle that step yourself.

Comment: You mention that you want to merge n sorted lists. How would we merge all those lists into n space if there n lists themselves occupy more than n space?

Comment: @maregor A list is not stored explicitly. Instead, we just store a pointer to where we stopped traversing that list. For example, if we now want the 4th element of 9th list, we know it is `a9 + b4`. If we choose to consume (output) that element, the pointer in that list moves to its 5th value, `a9 + b5`. The pointer is just a number from `1` to `n+1`, the last one meaning the list is already exhausted.

Comment: So the sorting time for both arrays is just O(nlogn) + O(nlogn) right?

Comment: @maregor Yeah, as they are both of size `n`, and we sort them independently.

Comment: @Palcente That depends on [pivot selection strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164163/quicksort-choosing-the-pivot).

Comment: quicksort runs at O(n lg n) on average and O(n^2) in worst case (if the arrays are already sorted)...

Comment: Once both arrays are sorted, I was thinking of having a pointer at each array to add up the sums and print them but it may not work well and the O(n) space may not be used. Should I just store the first list in the O(n) space and compare other possible lists to it?

Comment: @maregor I don't know how to do that with two pointers only. Imagine `n = 10` and the pointers are at `(5, 5)`, thus pointing at the sum `a5 + b5`. How do you find what's next? It may well be `a4 + b7`, `a1 + b6` or `a6 + b2`. That said, I don't claim such a solution is impossible, I just don't see it.

Comment: That's true, so that's a bad idea. But how would using n space make it work?

Comment: @maregor For each row `i`, we remember `j` pointing at the sum `ai + bj` we stopped on.

Answer (score 3):

In python you can something like that:

```
import heapq

a = [2, 1, 3]
b = [4, 6, 5]

a.sort()
b.sort()

def add_to_b(x):
    for v in b:
        yield v + x

for v in heapq.merge(*[add_to_b(x) for x in a]):
    print v
```

Result:

```
5
6
6
7
7
7
8
8
9
```

The idea is that we sort both arrays. Then adding to `b` an element of `a` defines a generator of increasing numbers. So we create `n` such generators and we merge them using `heapq.merge`. A generator, represented by `add` function above, at a specific time needs constant space (space needed to keep the current position in `b`). `heapq.merge` itself needs linear space. So we need linear space for the execution of the algorithm.

Comment: Wow, that's one short implementation! Python really shines here.

Comment: Could you explain for v in heapq.merge(*map(add, a)):? I'm not really good at python and could use some explanation.

Comment: `[add_to_b(x) for x in a]` will create a generator for each `x` belonging to `a`. The generator adds `x` to each element of `b`. We pass this sequence of generators to `heapq.merge` that will merge them.

Comment: The add_to_b adds all v elements in b, but you are passing all elements in a to it. How can I visualize what is happening there?

Comment: if `a = [1, 2, 3]`,  `b = [4, 5, 6]` then `add_to_b(1)` will generate `1 + 4,  1 + 5, 1 + 6`, `add_to_b(2)` will generate `2 + 4,  2 + 5, 2 + 6`,  `add_to_b(3)` will generate `3 + 4,  3 + 5, 3 + 6`. So we have 3 sequences a) `5, 6, 7` b) `6, 7, 8` c) `7, 8, 9` that need to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

First sort the 2 arrays in ascending order, the time complexity is `2 * O(n*lgn)`, which can be also regarded as `O(n*lgn)`. Then use a ***max heap*** with length `n + 1` to maintain the minimum n sums.

How to maintain the minimum n sums? First push `a1 + b1`, `a1 + b2`, `a1 + b3`, ..., `a1 + bn` to the heap. Then for every `a[i], 1 <= i < n` and `b[j], 0 <= j < n`, push `a[i] + b[j]` and then pop the largest one:

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
    heap.push_into(a[0] + b[j]);
}
for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {
        heap.push_into(a[i] + b[j]);
        heap.pop(); // remove the current largest sum in the heap, then the sums remain in the heap are the smallest n sums
    }
}
```

Then the n elements in the heap are the smallest n sums.

The time complexity is `O(n^2 * lgn)`, space complexity is `O(n)`.