# implement Quicksort in C

Tags: c, quicksort

What I want to do is quick-sort this 12 integer datas `{2,3,11,9,12,2,6,15,18,10,7,14}`.

And I should select the pivot `14` which is located in index-11.

The env. of practice is *GCC*.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DATA_SIZE 12
void quick_sort(int *list, int left, int right);
int partition(int *list, int left, int right);
void SWAP(int *x, int *y, int *t) { *t = *x; *x = *y; *y = *t; }
/*main start*/
int main() {
    //Initialize data[] for sorting
    int data[DATA_SIZE] = {2,3,11,9,12,2,6,15,18,10,7,14};
    quick_sort(data, 0, DATA_SIZE-1);
    for(int i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; i++) { printf("%d\t",data[i]);}
    return 0;
}

/*Main fuction for recursion.*/
void quick_sort(int *list, int left, int right) {
    if(left < right) {
        //Pivot selection
        int q = partition(list, left, right);
        //Divide
        quick_sort(list, left, q-1);
        quick_sort(list, q+1, right);
    }
}

/*Devide and Conquere*/
int partition(int *list, int left, int right) {
    int pivot;              //pivot
    int temp;               //temporary variable
    int low;                
    int high;               

    // select 
    low = left;
    high = right+1;
    pivot = list[11];

    do {
        //proceed
        do low++; while(list[low]<pivot);
        do high--; while(list[high]>pivot);
        //pivot-comparison
        if(low < high) SWAP(&list[low],&list[high], &temp);
    }while(low < high);
    //swap after comparison
    SWAP(&list[left], &list[high], &temp);
    return high;
}
```

the result is in below.

`3 6 2 7 10 9 11 12 14 2 15 18`

As result is awkward, so I inserted `printf("pivot : %d\n", pivot);` in the `partition()`.

```
pivot : 14
pivot : 7
pivot : 6
pivot : 3
pivot : 11
pivot : 9
pivot : 15
```

So I fixed the code `high = right+1;` in the `partition()` to  `high = right`.

```
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
pivot : 14
```

but the sort result is

`11 3 12 9 6 2 10 7 18 15 2 14`

Comment: You might want to do some more research about [how to choose pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot). Especially in regards to *hard-coding* it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That may affect performance, not the end result.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I know the importance of pivot selection, but I just wanted to try the fixed-pivot. thanks.

Comment: Then use `right` instead of the hard-coded `11` as index.

Comment: I also suggest you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), especially learn how to use a *debugger* to step through the code line by line. Doing that, while monitoring all variables, should help in finding and solving problems like this.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I use *GCC* compiler, Could I ask about how to use debugger of GCC ? or just url link.

Comment: Is this for personal use? C has "qsort" for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is wrong: You don't define a pivot but you define an algorithm that selects a pivot. Examples for algorithms are

- Pick the first element.
- Pick an element in the middle.
- Pick a random element.

The last one is practically the most important one. However, for training purposes, use the first one. The point is that using a deterministic behaviour makes it easier to debug. The random pivot can come later, in the spirit of "Devide and Conquer".

Comment: You can find [Quicksort: Choosing the Pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164163/) for some other options.  For big enough data sets, some implementations use a median of three medians of three.

Comment: Maybe Can I reverse the values of `data[]`?

Comment: I don't understand your question, @robineu.

Comment: `{2,3,11,9,12,2,6,15,18,10,7,14}` to `{14,7,10,18,15,6,2,12,9,11,3,2}` @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: You can also delete your data altogether, an empty sequence is always properly sorted. Sorry, it's still not clear what you want to know. Anyhow, here's an advise: Try it! If it fails and you don't understand why, use a debugger to step through to gain that understanding.

Answer (score 2):

```
pivot = list[11];
```

> And I should select the pivot 14 which is located in index-11.

No, it is not `index 11`. It's the right-most element of each sub list, not some hard coded index. By choosing an invalid pivot element, partitioning stops working.